# Boolean Algebra Question (Logic Circuits)

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

I'm stuck on an engineering question about boolean algebra.
I've been trying all day and asked my other students however I am still stuck. Could you please help me to draw a logic diagram and truth table for the Boolean expression "(A + B) . (A + C)". I also need to minimize the expression and do a logic circuit and truth table for it also.

---

I tried first attempt and got this:

[image]

However I am not sure if it was right so I started researching and got this for my second attempt:

[image]

I haven't completed the truth table, it's wrong I think.
Could you guys comment on which attempt was the correct one, thank you!

---

My final attempt:

[image]

Please tell me someone, is this finally correct? Both truth tables and logic diagrams?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  We do not mind helping if you show us what you have tried.  Homework with no attempt at a solution is locked.  Multiply it out and reduce.

Comment: Try looking up "Distributive Law"

Comment: And I looked up distributive law, Andy. Is there a certain method i'm supposed to follow when I minimise the expression for the second part of the question? Thank you!

Comment: Given you were asked to draw a truth table first, it might be possible to derive the minimized expression right from it. There are many ways to minimize an expression. You should probably use the one taught in the classroom.

Comment: Sorry Eugene, I really do suck at boolean algebra as i'm new to it in Engineering. Please check my screenshot(s) and would it be possible for someone to tell me the first drawing/truth table is correct?

Comment: Well, the schematic is wrong. Seems like you have confused between AND and OR gates...

Comment: Sorry, I can't edit it into the main post because I need more than 10 reputation. Which diagram is wrong, the the top or the bottom diagram? Or both?

Comment: The top one is incorrect.  "+" in Boolean is "OR", and "." is "AND".  You have drawn AND gates where OR gates should be and vice-versa.

Comment: Ok thank you Chris, is the bottom one fine? I'll be editing the top diagram right now! What about the top truth table, is it okay to stay the same?

Comment: The bottom one is incorrect as well.  Go through the truth table again for the upper one and think about the outputs of each gate once you've corrected the diagram.  From that, you should be able to see a pattern relating to what conditions give a final output of 1, and construct a simplified diagram.

Comment: I have made all the amendments stated in the above comments, here is the final attempt:
http://image.prntscr.com/image/b9b38f0acb904c31a96bdb990e1ae893.png
Could someone verify that this is all correct now? Took me some time, I hope its right now! :)

Comment: You have multiple errors in the A+C column in your top truth-table resulting in an error in the right-hand column.

Comment: Two errors, in fact.

Comment: Ok thank you guys, I really appreciate the help; I'm pretty tired and I must have made a mistake looking at another column when I was completing the truth table. I have amended the errors in the top truth table:
http://prntscr.com/f69c8e
I now see a pattern in the last column for both truth tables. Are  both logic diagrams and truth tables fully corrected now? I couldn't thank you guys enough! Took me a few hours lol, pretty bad at it.

Comment: Could someone confirm this piece of work is fully corrected now? 
    http://prnt.sc/f69c8e
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

$$(A + B) \cdot (A + C) $$
Distributive.  Multiply out terms.
$$ AA + AC + BA + BC $$
Idempotent
$$ A + AC + BA + BC $$
Distributive again.  Seek common factors.
$$ A (1 + C + B) + BC $$
Annulment
$$ A + BC $$
[Laws and Theorems of Boolean Algebra](https://www.mi.mun.ca/users/cchaulk/misc/boolean.htm)